# php codes stops running halfway through

Tags: php

I have created a php function that allows users to save their address on the database. My issue is that part of the code doesn't run at all. The code stops running at `$result2= "SELECT * FROM Addressv4 WHERE Userid = '".$id."'";`

It then starts working when it reaches this line of code  `$insert_query = "INSERT INTO Addressv4 (Userid, Housenumber, Street, Town, Postcode, DefaultAddress) 
    values ('$id', '$Number', '$Street', '$Town','$Postcode', '1')";`

I haven't received any syntax errors when running the code either.

Any help would be grateful.

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Getting data from HTML Form
$Number = $_POST['streetnumber'];
$Street = $_POST['street'];
$Town = $_POST['town'];
$Postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$Username = $_POST['Username'];

$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Userv2 WHERE Username = '".$Username."'");

if ($sql){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        $id = $row['Id'];

    }
}

$result2= "SELECT * FROM Addressv4 WHERE Userid = '".$id."'";

$sql1 = mysqli_query($connection, $result2);
$count = count($sql1);

if($count >=1){

    echo 'Sorry you can only have 1 default address';
}

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO Addressv4 (Userid, Housenumber, Street, Town, Postcode, DefaultAddress) 
values ('$id', '$Number', '$Street', '$Town','$Postcode', '1')";


$result = mysqli_query($connection, $insert_query);

header("Location: http://sots.brookes.ac.uk/~10031187/viewaddress.php");

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: how do you know that those lines between are not getting ran ?

Comment: When I have put an echo or a var dump between those lines nothing has happened

Comment: when you put a var_dump after $result2 = ....  it doesn't show ?

Comment: yes it doesn't show at all

Comment: Er..that's not quite possible It's a procedural code. Stops on error and doesn't execute after unless you have suppressed the error. On your PHP error reporting and try `echo mysqli_error($connection);` after all queries

Comment: Is display_errors set to ON in php.ini ? Did you try enabling all errors ? error_reporting(E_ALL); Did you check error logs ? Most likely errors are not showing blocked by your error reporting settings.

Comment: Do error handling when you are executing queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it's better to use

```
SELECT COUNT(Userid) AS countId FROM..
if ($row['countId'] > 1) {
```

that way the query will always return something, now there is a chance your query can return false..

what is the output of var_dump($sql1); ?

Answer (score 0):

$sql1 is a resulset. You cannot count the number of lines like this.
Try :

```
$sql1_count = mysqli_num_rows($sql1)
```